# "Building Your First App" app does not appear in launcher

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

Re android-sdk_r20.0.3-linux (on Debian Squeeze)

I'm attempting to follow the 'Building Your First App' tutorial using the command line tools.  The apk file gets created successfully and the 'adb install' also reports 'success', both installing into the emulator and onto a razr maxx (Android 4.0.4).  But in both cases, the app does not appear in the launcher or in the the app manager.

Details:

The app was created with the command

> android \
>   create project \
>   --target android-16 \
>   --name AAP1 \
>   --path ~xxx/AAP1 \
>   --activity MainActivity \
>   --package com.aap1

The manifest (created by 'android create') is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.aap1"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this. I suspect there's some little change that would fix this, but nothing I've found suggests what it might be.

FYI I also tried this with the eclipse plugin and ran into the same problem.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">` 
 to

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Notice the "." before MainActivity

Comment: Thanks.  Could you tell me how to repackage the apk file after editing the manifest?  Adding the '.' to 'android create project' command doesn't seem to effect the manifest.  I.e. if I use '... --activity .MainActivity' or "... --activity ".MainActivity"' the '.' gets stripped out.

Comment: If you are using eclipse then just use the project clean option and rebuild your project.

Comment: I'm using the command line tools.  Re-running 'ant debug' rebuilds. NOW it works.  Thanks.